# GNU MCU Eclipse trouble flashing/debugging code to xmc4800 with JLink

Tags: microcontroller, eclipse, j-link

I'm trying to make GNU MCU Eclipse work with my XMC4800 Relax kit.
Eclipse compiles the program fine. But when I try to flash or debug the code JLink seems to hang on `Starting Target CPU...`
This is the output I get when I start the debugger:

```
SEGGER J-Link GDB Server V6.32b Command Line Version

JLinkARM.dll V6.32b (DLL compiled May  8 2018 18:28:22)

Command line: -if swd -device XMC4800-F144x2048 -endian little -speed 1000 -port 2331 -swoport 2332 -telnetport 2333 -vd -ir -localhostonly 1
-----GDB Server start settings-----
GDBInit file:                  none
GDB Server Listening port:     2331
SWO raw output listening port: 2332
Terminal I/O port:             2333
Accept remote connection:      localhost only
Generate logfile:              off
Verify download:               on
Init regs on start:            on
Silent mode:                   off
Single run mode:               off
Target connection timeout:     0 ms
------J-Link related settings------
J-Link Host interface:         USB
J-Link script:                 none
J-Link settings file:          none
------Target related settings------
Target device:                 XMC4800-F144x2048
Target interface:              SWD
Target interface speed:        1000kHz
Target endian:                 little

Connecting to J-Link...
J-Link is connected.
Firmware: J-Link Lite-XMC4200 Rev.1 compiled Apr  5 2017 11:59:07
Hardware: V1.00
S/N: 591105020
Checking target voltage...
Target voltage: 3.30 V
Listening on TCP/IP port 2331
Connecting to target...Connected to target
Waiting for GDB connection...Connected to 127.0.0.1
Reading all registers
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x00000000 (Data = 0x2000FF3C)
Read 2 bytes @ address 0x00000000 (Data = 0xFF3C)
Received monitor command: speed 1000
Target interface speed set to 1000 kHz
Received monitor command: clrbp
Received monitor command: reset
Resetting target
Received monitor command: halt
Halting target CPU...
...Target halted (PC = 0x08000200)
Received monitor command: regs
R0 = E000ED08, R1 = 00000263, R2 = 02000080, R3 = C8000201
R4 = 00000536, R5 = 00000000, R6 = 00000000, R7 = 00000000
R8 = 00000000, R9 = 0C000004, R10= 00000000, R11= 00000000
R12= 00000000, R13= 1FFE8800, MSP= 1FFE8800, PSP= 00000000
R14(LR) = 000000ED, R15(PC) = 08000200
XPSR 01000000, APSR 00000000, EPSR 01000000, IPSR 00000000
CFBP 00000000, CONTROL 00, FAULTMASK 00, BASEPRI 00, PRIMASK 00
Reading all registers
Received monitor command: speed auto
Select auto target interface speed (1875 kHz)
Received monitor command: flash breakpoints 1
Flash breakpoints enabled
Received monitor command: semihosting enable
Semi-hosting enabled (Handle on BKPT)
Received monitor command: semihosting IOClient 1
Semihosting I/O set to TELNET Client
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x08000200 (Data = 0xD074F8DF)
Read 2 bytes @ address 0x08000200 (Data = 0xF8DF)
Downloading 40 bytes @ address 0x00000000 - Verify failed
Downloading 2 bytes @ address 0x00000028 - Verify failed
Writing register (PC = 0x00000028)
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x00000028 (Data = 0xF0116801)
Received monitor command: clrbp
Received monitor command: reset
Resetting target
Received monitor command: halt
Halting target CPU...
...Target halted (PC = 0x08000200)
Received monitor command: regs
R0 = E000ED08, R1 = 00000263, R2 = 02000080, R3 = C8000201
R4 = 00000536, R5 = 00000000, R6 = 00000000, R7 = 00000000
R8 = 00000000, R9 = 0C000004, R10= 00000000, R11= 00000000
R12= 00000000, R13= 1FFE8800, MSP= 1FFE8800, PSP= 00000000
R14(LR) = 000000ED, R15(PC) = 08000200
XPSR 01000000, APSR 00000000, EPSR 01000000, IPSR 00000000
CFBP 00000000, CONTROL 00, FAULTMASK 00, BASEPRI 00, PRIMASK 00
Reading all registers
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x08000200 (Data = 0xD074F8DF)
Read 2 bytes @ address 0x08000200 (Data = 0xF8DF)
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x000000EC (Data = 0x489BE004)
Read 2 bytes @ address 0x000000EC (Data = 0xE004)
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x000000EC (Data = 0x489BE004)
Read 2 bytes @ address 0x000000EC (Data = 0xE004)
Starting target CPU...
```

then it looks like the program wasn't flashed, the old program is still running. (I checked this by changing some simple parameters).

When I flash the program with CLI everything works as expected. I run this line (inside a makefile):

```
echo -e "connect\ndevice XMC4800-F144x2048\nspeed 1000\nsi swd\nloadfile xmc4800-ecat-slave.hex\ng\nqc\n" | ../JLink_Linux_V632b_x86_64/JLinkExe
```

Now I don't have a lot of experience with this, so I have trouble finding out what exactly is going wrong. If someone can show me whats going wrong I would be a happy man. Right now I'm just randomly changing settings...

I used [this](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/debug/jlink/) tutorial to set everything up

All my settings are shown in this album: https://i.stack.imgur.com/caiu3.jpg

Comment: Looks OK to me. The control is transferred to the flashed program. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I clarified the question a bit: The old program is still running on the MCU, not the new one. So it looks like it's not flashing correctly

Comment: Post screenshots of your debugging setup. Take pictures of each tab in the debug configuration

Comment: Actually I see some `Verify failed` lines

Comment: Done; see this album: https://imgur.com/a/O0np0r7

Comment: Settings look sane. I would check what your flash write protection status is. The relevent Ref Manual section is 8.4.8.3. The TLDR is that you will check the "FSR" (Flash status register: 8.7.3.1) to see if the write protect bits are high (Bits 21, 22, 23). If they are, you'll have to research about unlocking them.

Comment: Will look into that, thanks. Just to be sure; when I flash the program with the "original" makefile it works fine (command is shown in the question)

Comment: You may have Eclipse project errors you suppressed. In which case it is possible you are launching and simply attaching to the running program. Go in to eclipse prefs and check to make sure this is set: https://imgur.com/a/s39aUok

Comment: Try using jflash to download the flash contents and verify it is flashing as expected.

Comment: @pgvoorhees I have exactly the same settings as you have.

Comment: @gregb212 flashing works fine when I use JLinkExe.

Comment: So I just turned on all the warnings (except "Generate errors instead of warnings"). Now the program doesn't compile anymore, get loads of: "linker input file unused because linking not done". Could this be the problem? (Is something I will certainly take a look at, doesn't seem good anyway)

Comment: You can post your top-level project settings. There are a lot of them that need to be checked. But, I would focus on your linker section, make sure the script eclipse is using is the same as what make is using; I would also snapshot any build steps configs you've got and artifact settings. But at this point, your range of possibilities is starting to get wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Downloading 40 bytes @ address 0x00000000 - Verify failed
Downloading 2 bytes @ address 0x00000028 - Verify failed
```

This means that writing at 0x0 is not possible.

Your device is either somehow protected to write, or the memory map used in your program does not match the device memory map; some devices use a higher address to write the flash.

Comment: You're welcome. Please confirm the answer.